# With PHP, how to remove CSV row if ID column is duplicate?

Tags: php, csv

My goal is to with PHP, remove the entire row of a CSV-file if duplicate values appears in a **certain column**, in this example **ID-column**. I naturally want to keep the first row where the duplicated ID appears (see example below).

I don't want to create a new CSV-file, I want to open the file, remove what needs to be removed, and overwrite the current file.

I also want to store how many rows that has been removed in variable.

#### Input (notice duplicate ID of 3): **file.csv**

```
ID,Date,Name,Age
1,12/3/13,John Doe ,23
2,12/3/19,Jane Doe ,21
3,12/4/19,Jane Doe ,19
3,12/3/18,John Doe  ,33
4,12/3/19,Jane Doe ,21
```

#### Expected output: **file.csv**

```
ID,Date,Name,Age
1,12/3/13,John Doe ,23
2,12/3/19,Jane Doe ,21
3,12/4/19,Jane Doe ,19
4,12/3/19,Jane Doe ,21
```

And then also be able to: `echo $removedRows;` that will output: 1
How to accomplish this?

---

I've managed to get this in a new file, but I just want to overwrite the current file and i dont know why i got the " " around name column:

```
ID,Date,Name,Age
1,12/3/13,"John Doe ",23
2,12/3/19,"Jane Doe ",21
3,12/4/19,"Jane Doe ",19
4,12/3/19,"Jane Doe ",21
```

With the following code:

```
$input_filename = 'file.csv';

// Move the csv-file to 'newfile' directory
copy($input_filename, 'newfile/'.$input_filename);

$output_filename = 'newfile/'.$input_filename;

$input_file = fopen($input_filename, 'r');
$output_file = fopen($output_filename, 'w');

$IDs = array();

// Read the header
$headers = fgetcsv($input_file, 1000);
fputcsv($output_file, $headers);

// Flip it so it becomes name => ID
$headers = array_flip($headers);

// Read every row
while (($row = fgetcsv($input_file, 1000)) !== FALSE)
{
    $ID = $row[$headers['ID']];
    // Do we already have this ID?
    if (isset($IDs[$ID]))
        continue;

    // Mark this ID as being found
    $IDs[$ID] = true;
    // Write it to the output
    fputcsv($output_file, $row);
}
```

Comment: This is `i want to` text. And we need __questions__ here. Did you try anything? Some code maybe?

Comment: Sorry you are right, updated.

Comment: Is the file always sorted by the id? If not how big can it be? Will anything else try to access the file at the same time as your script? In the absence of an answer to these questions NO SOLUTION to your problem is valid. There are many reasons for using DBMS rather than text files for maintaining data - you may want to consider some of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you cannot read from a file and write to it at the same time, I advise you to write your data to another file and then move this file to your source file, something like:

```
$input_filename = 'file.csv';
$output_filename = 'newfile/' . $input_filename;

// Copy the csv-file to 'newfile' directory
copy($input_filename, $output_filename);
$input_file = fopen($input_filename, 'r');
$output_file = fopen($output_filename, 'w');

$IDs = array();

// Read the header
$headers = fgetcsv($input_file, 1000);
fputcsv($output_file, $headers);

// Flip it so it becomes name => ID
$headers = array_flip($headers);

// Deleted rows counter
$rows_deleted = 0;
// Read every row
while (($row = fgetcsv($input_file, 1000)) !== FALSE)
{
    $ID = $row[$headers['ID']];
    // Do we already have this ID?
    if (isset($IDs[$ID])) {
        // row skipped - therefore it is deleted
        $rows_deleted++;
        continue;
    }

    // Mark this ID as being found
    $IDs[$ID] = true;
    // Write it to the output
    fputcsv($output_file, $row);
}

// Now we should move output file to input one
rename($output_filename, $input_filename);

echo "Deleted: " . $rows_deleted;
```

As for `"` around your data - this is a result of `fputcsv`. This is for safety reasons. Imagine if your data will be not

```
3,12/4/19,Jane Doe ,19
```

but

```
3,12/4/19,Jane, Doe ,19
```

And you want to consider `Jane, Doe` as one element. That's why with `"` it's more clear for a parser how to treat your rows:

```
3,12/4/19,"Jane, Doe ",19    // here `Jane, Doe` is one element
```

Usually, wrapping data in `"` does not affect parsing generated csv. But **if** you're sure that you don't want quotes - you can pass more [arguments to `fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#refsect1-function.fputcsv-parameters), though I'm not sure if it will work with empty value as `enclosure` argument.

Comment: Empty enclosure needs workaround. Sth like this would do: `fputs($output_file, implode(',', $row) . PHP_EOL);`

Comment: Works perfect! I let the enclosure be for obvious reasons, thanks for the lecture @u_mulder. Any suggestion on how to store "how many rows were deleted" ?

Comment: Awesome @u_mulder, thanks a lot! Any suggestion on how to store the deleted rows in an array to be able to log what rows was removed?

Comment: Add them to array before `continue`